# Visual Studio 2013 and git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

In VS 2013 I have Microsoft Git Provider. Do I need to install [git client](http://git-scm.com/downloads) for local repo or it's already included in VS?

Comment: You don't *need* to install anything, but you will almost certainly *want* to install Git for Windows (and posh-git!) if you want to use the command-line.  http://www.woodwardweb.com/git/setting_up_the.html is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not install anything else if you'll only use git from inside the Team Explorer.  I personally prefer to use the git command line and [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/), so I install both of these and avoid the Visual Studio git window.

Comment: From VS I can upload code to git repo on Visual Studio Online. But if I want to use GitHub, can I still use only Team Explorer in VS?

Comment: Yes, Team Explorer hooks to any Git repository: GitHub, Visual Studio Online, Source Forge, an on-premise Git repository, a directory on a file share, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install any git client. Microsoft has integrated Git in Visual Studio 2013. I suggest you can read this article [Using Git-TFS in Visual Studio 2013 Express](http://www.codepool.biz/general/using-git-tfs-in-visual-studio-2013-express.html), which explains specifically how to use git in visual studio.

Comment: no, you have to install the command tool if you want. There's a help doc on Microsoft's website - [Work from the Git command prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286572.aspx#setup_install)

Comment: That link seems dead now.

Comment: @Christian Wilkie, I just checked it. It's still working